# Get Unique Reads by User

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table Structure is very simple:

```
UserId    ReportId
```

I have a query such as this:

```
SELECT UserId, COUNT(*) AS 'ReportsRead'
FROM MyReports
GROUP BY UserId
```

Essentially this will give me the total number of read reports by each user. What I am trying to figure out is how do I get total number of unique reports that each user has read. So if he reads a report 10 times with the id of 1, it will count as 1.

I have tried adding ReportId to Select and Group by, but all that does is gives me the total over few rows. What i want is to get that total in a single row. Is it possible without doing a subquery?

Comment: use `count(distinct reportid)` instead of `count(*)`

Comment: Do you want to consider NULLs while taking distinct count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `count(distinct)`:

```
SELECT UserId, COUNT(DISTINCT reportId) AS ReportsRead
FROM MyReports
GROUP BY UserId;
```

Don't enclose column aliases in single quotes.  Only use single quotes for date and string constants.

Comment: Off topic question, why not enclose them in single quotes? I think I know the answer but would like to hear your reasoning.

Comment: @Bojan . . . Single quotes should only be used for string and date constants.  Although you can define a column alias using single quotes, you cannot refer to it later that way -- a cause of bugs in queries.